# Grant your originating account the Service Account Token Creator role on the target service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, service-accounts, google-iam

I used the below command to Authenticate in MAC OS terminal

```
gcloud auth login
```

It redirects to the google login page and show the authentication process successful.

While using the command

```
gsutil -i fetebird-storage@fetebird.iam.gserviceaccount.com ls
```

Getting an exception as

```
AccessDeniedException: Service account impersonation failed. Please go to the Google Cloud Platform Console (https://cloud.google.com/console), select IAM & admin, then Service Accounts, and grant your originating account the Service Account Token Creator role on the target service account.
```

However, on the cloud I do have given the permission as shown below

[image]

[image]

Auth List

[image]

Comment: Linked to the other question. Can you perform a `gcloud config list` and paste the result?

Comment: this is the same on my side. I suggest to raise a bug. according to google doc it should be done by "Send Feedback" button (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests) and I think this is the page https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions where `-i` option is described

Comment: I wrote several articles about service account impersonation: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/ You are not setting up the requires roles on the correct resources. My article shows the steps required.

Comment: @JohnHanley If I run the command from cloud shell everything is working fine, however, from the MAC OS Terminal I am not able to run

Comment: What is a terminal?

Comment: @JohnHanley Mac os terminal

Comment: What does `gcloud auth list` display for each environment? Are they using the same "Active Account"?

Comment: Yes they are using the same active account, paste the screenshot above

Comment: Compare the output on the system that works and the one that does not.

Comment: Not at all able to access from the MAC terminal, getting an exception as (gcloud.projects.get-iam-policy) User [fetebird@gmail.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [fetebird:getIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission. What API do I need to enable for this

Comment: Your screenshot shows that fetebird@gmail.com is an Owner. You do not need additional roles to perform IAM tasks on the "owned" project. You must have a configuration error such as project spelling mistake, etc. Execute `gcloud auth revoke` within macOS. Then reboot the machine. Execute `gcloud auth login` with the correct user, select the correct Project ID (not project name) `gcloud config set project <PROJECT_ID>` and try again.

Comment: Hi @SanJaisy, were you able to solve this issue mate?

Answer (score 2):

The current logged in user (fetebird@gmail.com) must have the Service Account Access Token Creator role.

You might think the owner role would be sufficient, however, when I tested this myself you need to explicitly add it to the account that is impersonating the service account.

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#token-creator-role